# How do I know my metabase domain for certbot htpps configuration?

Tags: docker, shell, nginx, certbot, metabase

I ran this command on the shell: sudo certbot --nginx

It produced this output:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Please enter the domain name(s) you would like on your certificate (comma and/or
space separated) (Enter 'c' to cancel):

The operating system my web server runs on is: lubuntu

I can login to a root shell on my machine.

The version of certbot is 1.21.0

I'm trying to set up a https for my team have access to a database information the is on metabase. I created a metabase local connection with docker but I don't understand any of this!
My nginx information are saved on a file as:

```
server {
  server_name             domain.com;

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header Proxy  "";
  proxy_redirect          off;

  location /metabase/ {
    proxy_pass            http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

do I have to edit this with personalized domain name or that is already one?

Comment: What's the domain name for your server? That's what you need to use in your nginx conf, and also when you create the certificate. Currently you have `domain.com` in your conf.

Comment: Do I have to made up one on the file? @super

Comment: I don't know if the server is metabase or I have to create one @super

Comment: No, you need an registered domain name that points to your server. Metabase or not has nothing to do with this.